# How to insert into aonther SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tblOriginal` which looks like this (and has no primary key):

```
employeeId code amount date
-----------------------------
emp01      sbk  10000  201501
emp02      sbk  10002  201501
emp02      cka  2000   201501
emp03      sbk  10003  201501
emp04      sbk  10004  201501
emp01      sbk  20000  201502
emp01      dgr  5000   201502
emp02      sbk  20002  201501
emp02      qaw  2000   201502
emp02      dng  4000   201502
emp03      sbk  20003  201502
emp04      sbk  20004  201502
```

What I need to do get all data with the code sbk into a table named `tblEmp` (`employeeId` is the primary key) to look as follows:

```
employeeId code amount date   amount2 date2
----------------------------------------------
emp01      sbk  10000  201501 20000   201502
emp02      sbk  10002  201501 20002   201501
emp03      sbk  10003  201501 20003   201502
emp04      sbk  10004  201501 20004   201502
```

And then get the remaining data into another table named `tblOthers` to look as follows. Primary key is also `employeeId`

```
employeeId code amount date   code2 amount2 date2
--------------------------------------------------
emp02      cka  2000   201501
emp01      dgr  5000   201502
emp02      qaw  2000   201502 dng   4000    201502
```

My problem is I don't know how to take data which has the same name into a `employeeId` into the tables and store the data into the columns

Any help will be appreciate.

All tables have been created

Comment: insert into t1 select ... from ... where...

Comment: I thought of it but my problem is on the `tblOriginal` there is data with the same **employeeId** but different dates yet the `tblEmp` and `tblOthers` the **employeeId** is my `PRIMARY KEY` so there shouldn't be data with the same **employeeId**

Comment: There are some problems with your tblOthers table. If EmployeeId is primary key, it can not contains 2 rows with the same employeeId emp02.

Comment: @HuyHoangPham tblOriginal doesn't have any Primary key

Comment: "And then get the remaining data into another table named tblOthers to look as follows. PRIMARY KEY is also employeeId". The sample tblOthers table below this sentence has duplicate primary key emp02.

Comment: Your Schema violates the basic rules or Normalization, You are repeating data over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

if there is absolutely 2 amount you can use some thing like this for the other table

```
;with temp as (
select empemployeeId,
lag(amount,1,null) over (partition by empemployeeId ORDER BY date ASC) as amount,
lag(date,1,null) over (partition by empemployeeId ORDER BY date ASC) as date,
lag(amount,1,null) over (partition by empemployeeId ORDER BY date DESC) as amount2,
lag(date,1,null) over (partition by empemployeeId ORDER BY date DESC) as date2,
from tblOriginal 
)
select empemployeeId,'sdk',amount,date,amount2,date2 into tblEmp  from temp to
where to.code='sdk'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Please refer this link :**

> *http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp*

SQL AND & OR operators are used to filter records based on more than one condition.

**AND** Operator Example -

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' AND City='Berlin';
```

**OR** Operator Example -

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City='Berlin' OR City='München';
```

**Combining AND & OR** -

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' AND (City='Berlin' OR City='München');
```